# How to use variables as options in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, variables

I am creating a dropdown when I type in a search field with preselected products that I am retrieving from php. The products from php will be stored in the arrayData variable. What I am trying to do is set my options in the array to be what is in the arrayData variable. The result I am currently getting is one line of string -> "Option1","Option2","Option3","Option4","Option5". I want each option to be a separate option in the array instead of just one line of string with the "" still there. Any way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
var arrayData = "\"Option1\",\"Option2\",\"Option3\",\"Option4\",\"Option5\""

var array = [arrayData]
```

var array ["option1","option2","option3"] works fine when when I manually put the options in but these options will be dynamic from php.

when I hold the options in a variable and try to put the variable inside the array it just display the string a a whole and doesn't make each option separate.

How do you make the arrayData variable act as part of the array instead of a string? Where each option is its own separate thing like it would be if I did it without the variable. I am trying to word this question the best that I can.

Comment: Do you just mean `var array = ["a", "b", "c"];` ?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is instead of ["a", "b", "c"] is [variable] that holds "a", "b", "c" etc. The reason for this is because the options (abc) will change in the database as the user adds and removes products.

Comment: So then what about an object? `var d = { "a" : ["b", "c"], "d" : ["e", "f"]};`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting json string. So, You need to convert to array

I made one fuction for convert json string to array

```
func getObjectFromJsonString(jsonString : String) -> Any?
{
    var sObject : Any?
    if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    {
        do
        {
            sObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return sObject
}
```

You can use this as below

```
if let dataArray = self.getObjectFromJsonString(jsonString: yourString) as? [String]
{
    print(dataArray) ---> ["Option1","Option2"...]
}
```